# location.href after successful login

Tags: javascript, authentication, form-submit

I have a login form and a xhr that checks credentials

If the credentials are fine I get token and want to redirect user to some page

Here is the form

```
<form method="post" action="" class="login" onsubmit="getToken()"> {% csrf_token %}
<p>
  <label for="login">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="login">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="password">
</p>
<p class="login-submit">
  <button type="submit">Log in</button>
</p>
```

And here is js:

```
function getToken(){
        document.cookie = "path=/; csrftoken = {% csrf_token %}";
        //alert($.cookie('csrftoken'));
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'api_url', false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"username":document.getElementById("login").value,
                    "password":document.getElementById("password").value}));
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            alert( "Введите корректную комбинацию логина и пароля!" );

                    }
        else {
            alert( xhr.responseText );
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
            document.cookie = "token = " + JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).key;
                }

}
```

However, after a successful login I get an alert with token and the cookie is set, but the page just refreshes.

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

doesn't work...

Comment: Are you trying to send them to a relative url or a fully qualified url like http://www.google.com? `window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";` works, so the issue has to be with something else

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in a simplified jsfiddle rendition?

Comment: @RobM. I tried both ways, it just doesn't work. There is nothing else on the page or is js

Comment: Try `return false` at the end of `getToken()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false from your event handler to prevent the default form submission:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="login" onsubmit="return getToken()">
```

And then return false in your event handler:

```
function getToken(){
   document.cookie = "path=/; csrftoken = {% csrf_token %}";
   //alert($.cookie('csrftoken'));
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('POST', 'api_url', false);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
   xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"username":document.getElementById("login").value, "password":document.getElementById("password").value}));
   if (xhr.status != 200) {
       alert( "Введите корректную комбинацию логина и пароля!" );
   } else {
       alert( xhr.responseText );
       window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
       document.cookie = "token = " + JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).key;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? They are not preventing the default event from firing?

Comment: it shouldn't be necessary to cancel default action since he's just redirecting anyway.

Comment: also, without using the callback it's always going to hit the alert.

Comment: @Pamblam they don't need the callback, they are performing a JAX request, the third parameter is for `async`, and `false` means that the request will perform synchronously. As for the default action, it is kind of a race condition and most likely it will perform the form submit over redirecting

Comment: JS is single threaded. There is no such thing as a race condition in JS. I realize it's sync, but still the value of `xhr.status` is different at different points during the lifetime of the request. It should always start out as pending before changing to 200. Without the callback, it should always hit the alert first since it will never be 200 right off the bat. @RobM.

Comment: @Pamblam I see your point, it's not necessarily a classical "race condition", but more of a potential timing issue that I feel like "race condition" basically describes. Either way, I'm wrong because it's synchronous :P  AFAIK the `xhr.status` condition won't be executed until the synchronous `xhr.open` call completes, so in this way `xhr.status` will not have a "live" value as it typically does when executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

you sorta left out a pretty big part of the xhr.. you need the `onreadystatechange` call or nothing is ever going to happen.

```
function getToken(){
    document.cookie = "path=/; csrftoken = {% csrf_token %}";
    //alert($.cookie('csrftoken'));
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'api_url', false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"username":document.getElementById("login").value,
                "password":document.getElementById("password").value}));

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ // <-- you need this..

        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            alert( "Введите корректную комбинацию логина и пароля!" );

                }
        else {
            alert( xhr.responseText );
            window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
            document.cookie = "token = " + JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).key;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: No they didn't, `xhr.open('POST', 'api_url', false);`. `false` causes the request to be synchronous

Comment: I use sync request, so there is no need in onreadystatechange handler. Nevertheless, how is it possible for alert to appear and .href not working?

Comment: because the response will never be 200 at first. it will be something else first, then change to 200 once the connection is successful. that's why you need the event listener. the event listener will be called more than once, so you also need to make sure it's 200/